# void pointer to function

Tags: c, function-pointers, void-pointers

I need an explanaton. I searched for an answer but couldn't find one.

The problem is as follows:
I'm working on exercises from the book: "Programming for Engineers" A.R. Bradley Chapter 7
Here's part of the code:

```
struct _fifo {
   unsigned capacity;
   unsigned head;
   unsigned tail;
   void * data[0];
};

fifo newFifo(int capacity) {
   // The capacity of a circular buffer is one less than one
   // would think: if the user wants a given capacity, the
   // required array is one cell larger.
   capacity++;

   fifo q = (fifo) malloc(sizeof(struct _fifo) + capacity * (sizeof(void *)));
   q->capacity = (unsigned) capacity;
   q->head = 0;
   q->tail = 0;
   return q;
}

int putFifo(fifo q, void * e) {

   if ((q->head+1) % q->capacity == q->tail) // full?
      return -1;
   q->data[q->head] = e;
   q->head = (q->head+1) % q->capacity;
   return 0;
}

typedef void (*printFn) (void*);

int printFifo(fifo q, printFn f) {

   unsigned i;
   for (i = q->tail; i != q->head; i = (i+1) % q->capacity) {
      f(q->data[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}

static void printLong(void * e) {
   // %ld tells printf to print a long integer
   printf("%ld", (long) e);
}

int main() {
   fifo longq;
   longq = newFifo(3);

   printFifo(longq, printLong);
   return 0;
}
```

My question is this:
in function printLong i'm passing void pointer e so does the cast (long) e makes that adress of e? how come i'm getting a value of data and not the address printed?

for example if i do this i'm getting the address printed not the value:

```
typedef void (*printFn) (void*);

static void printLong (void * e) {
   printf("%ld", (long) e);
}

int printL (void* l, printFn f) {
   f(l);
}

int main() 
{
   long a = 5;
   long* l = &a;

   printf("%ld\n", *l);
   printL(l, printLong);

   return 0;
}
```

but if i cast

```
*(long*) e
```

i'll get the value. How come first code part prints the value not the address?
I guess i don't see something so that's why i'm confused. Please help :)

Comment: Don't print pointer values like that. Use `%p` for your format specifier and just send the pointer. If you want to print the long pointed to by a pointer-to-long, then use %ld and dereference the pointer after an appropriate cast, but make sure it holds an address-of-long or you're walking into UB. Is there some specific reason you're not just declaring `long*` for your parameter type?

Comment: Does this code example come with a prefix, "Don't write code like this"? Can you include the code from "newFifo"? I'm trying to determine if the "void* data[0]" is an overlay hack or if it is cast-avoidance hack. Either way, there's hack-trickery going on that makes me think the book may need an addendum of exothermic oxidization.

Comment: I really, really hope this code is not taken from a book... "Programming by a would-be engineer"?

Comment: Are you forced to use this book, or is this your personal choice? If the latter - flush that one in the toilet and pick some reccomended by people who know C textbook. I doubt it will be one of them.

Comment: This book was recommended to me. I greatly enjoyed reading it. I'll add code for newFifo in main post as requested.

Comment: I see you post new portion of "how not to work on pointers in C". Good for you.

Comment: please be constructive, i'm not here to annoy all of you, i'm here to ask for help with understanding this topic

Comment: @bobmurley I constructively answered your question. You don't ask any additional questions so I assume you understand it.

Comment: if you refer to "If the latter - flush that one in the toilet and pick some reccomended by people who know C textbook" i certainly appreciate this suggestion and if i won't find answers for the questions asked I'll do as you suggested. still i hope to understand why two code parts differ in results they produce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in function printLong i'm passing void pointer e so does the cast
>   (long) e makes that adress of e? how come i'm getting a value of data
>   and not the address printed?

no. It casts the pointer to a long int. If you want to get the address of e, use &e instead. But e is already the address of a function... i see no point in getting the address of a argument because it is on the stack.

So basically I guess you might have some misunderstanding on functions.A function name is not like a var name:

- var_name has a value and you use &var_name to get the address
- function_name itself has the value of the address the function
  implementation and &function_name would return the same
  value(the same address).

UPDATE:

> I call f(q->data[i]); to get to printLong (void* e) - so shouldn't e
>   be pointing to q->data[i] ?

In C, function arguments are passed by value. 
The value of q->data[i] is passed to printLong() so the argument e would have the same value(the same address) as q->data[i]. so e is a copy of q->data[i]

Comment: I think i understand that, but what i don't see is how if the function printLong gets void pointer e (address?) and prints a value in that adress with (long) e - that is without dereferencing address

Comment: e holds an address but itself has an address to. you just cast it's value(so the address it stores) to long.

Comment: Yes, so i should have the address e holds printed - but code in first part of message prints the value not the address

Comment: Ok, i guess i don't see how e holds the address of a function. I call f(q->data[i]); to get to printLong (void* e) - so shouldn't e be pointing to q->data[i] ? i start to fell sorry for my questions as i see you're getting annoyed with my lack of understanding

Comment: In C, function arguments are passed by value. The value of q->data[i] is passed to printLong() so the argument e would have the same value(the same address) as q->data[i]. so e is a copy of q->data[i]

Comment: Well i think - thanks to you - that i finally got it. Of course i knew that in c arguments are passed by value but i didn't realize that i could pass long (or what i thought was long - q->data[i]) to a function expecting void pointer (of course i was passing void pointer thinking it was long). so everything works but... data is declared as void pointer type so it can store all sorts of types only if i am not mistaken i won't be able to store data of bigger than pointer size (double, long long?) will it?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view the only way it prints assigned values is by assigning them as addresses manually in your pointer.
**Example**

```
void * ptr=100;
printf("%ld", (long)ptr);
```

will print `100` on the screen, but trying to dereference it will cause (most likely) segmentation fault.

So considering the risks of this procedure and, well, nonsense of holding long integers in void* I'm against even considering this as useful piece of code.

Comment: I guess your answer is the same as what came out of discussion in the other one. Only perhaps yours was too concise for me to understand right away. Thank you.